# Update Firebase with the final score and display to user

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm getting the `score` and `topicTotal` from the state and printing them, however, I want to update Firebase with the `topicTotal` by retrieving `topicTotal` in `report`. Every way I try to access `topicTotal` in `report`, I get `null` in Firebase or `The getter 'topicTotal' was called on null`.

How can I access `topicTotal` in `report` and update Firebase with it? Also, how can I display `topicTotal` to the user?

```
set score(Options newValue) {
    var score = idx += newValue.score; 
    _score = newValue;              
    print(score);
    _score = newValue;  
    notifyListeners();
  }
  
  set topicTotal(Options newValue) {
    var topicTotal = idx;
    _score = newValue;
    this._topicTotal = newValue;
    print(topicTotal);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

model

```
class Report {
...
  int topicTotal;
 

  Report({ this.uid, this.topics, this.email, this.total, this.topicTotal, this.level, this.id, this.title, this.description, this.img });

  factory Report.fromMap(Map data) {
    return Report(
      uid: data['uid'],
      email: data['email'],
      total: data['total'] ?? 0,
      topics: data['topics'] ?? {},
      topicTotal: data['topicTotal'] ?? 34,
      level: data['level'] ?? 383,
      id: data['id'] ?? '',
      title: data['title'] ?? '',
      description: data['description'] ?? '',
      img: data['img'] ?? 'default.png',
    );
  }
}
```

Here I can access `total` but not `topicTotal`

```
 if (report != null)
              Text('${report.total ?? 0}',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display3),
            Text('Assessments Completed',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead),
            Spacer(),
            if (report != null)
            Text('your topic score is ${report.topicTotal ?? 0}'),
```

```
 onPressed: () {
                  _updateUserReportWithTopics(assessment, state, optionSelected);

Future<void> _updateUserReportWithTopics(Assessment assessment, AssessmentState state, Options optionSelected) {
  state.topicTotal = optionSelected;
  return Global.reportRef.upsert(
    ({
      'total': FieldValue.increment(1),
      'topics': {
        '${assessment.topic}': FieldValue.arrayUnion([
          assessment.title,
          assessment.topicTotal,
          assessment.questions.length,
        ]),
      },
      
      //'topicTotal': state.topicTotal = optionSelected
    }),
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `topicTotal` is recorded into the Firestore database? Can you see it on the Firebase console for that document? does the field has the same name or is it `topic_total`?

Comment: @MichelFeinstein Thanks for your comment. `topicTotal` does appear in the Firestore database and the name is exactly the same.

Comment: You call `notifyListeners` on all of your setters, so maybe you are updating the screen when one of your values is set, but `topiTotal` isn't set yet?

Comment: @MichelFeinstein Thanks, i've tried several changes here but nothing has worked.

Comment: Try making a minimal reproducible app